# Synthesize multiple action methods in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a dashboard-style application with lots of individual bits of the screen that load asynchronously. Each of these bits really makes sense as its own action on the page's controller. However, the data will load more quickly if we reduce the number of http requests to 1. I'm considering creating an action that just returns a combination of results from several smaller actions, such that the web client can GET the actions separately or together.  However, this seems like a hand-rolled solution to a common problem, so I'm wondering if there's built-in support for agglomerating actions in this way that I don't know about.  Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

In your core view, you can use the `Html.RenderAction()` method to render completely separate actions from another action.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use **ViewModel** containing all data needed for your dashboard and then create several partial views, feed them with data from ViewModel?

I have also an dashboard in my project, I did it this way and I am happy with the solution. I have DashboardController and its Index action just takes ViewModel (which aggregates all necesary data) and sends it to View. In that View, I have several partial views (each of them needs its own model) and I pass them data from my ViewModel. Inside that partial view are then references to specific actions (like CRUD for specific models).
When you do it this way, you can easily create partial views for specific models (Task, Project, User .. in my case). And then just use them as a pieces in your final layout. My ViewModel contains collections of Tasks, Projects and Users which I then simply pass to matching partial views.